# apache rewrite rule to convert space to hyphen

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Please consider the following url

```
http://example.com/ex/main/items/       a name    with     spaces  /72
```

I need a rewrite rule to add in .htaccess that will convert this to

```
http://example.com/ex/main/items/a-name-with-spaces/72
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*?)/[\s]+(.*?)$ /$1/$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)[\s]+/(.*?)$ /$1/$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)[\s]+(.*?)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Add those **before** any rules you may already have in your htaccess file.

Alternatively, you can add those to your vhost or server config. You'd just need to preface the pattern with a `/`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/(.*?)/[\s]+(.*?)$ /$1/$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/(.*?)[\s]+/(.*?)$ /$1/$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/(.*?)[\s]+(.*?)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it doesn't seem to work though..i am getting The requested URL [URL here] was not found on this server.